# Freaky dots in the complex plane

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, complex-numbers, periodic-functions

**Context:**

I recently saw user [@David](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/119775/david)'s profile picture and description:

[image: David's profile picture, a pretty complex shape with 20-fold rotational symmetry]

"My icon is the graph of the exponential sum 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10620}e^{2\pi if(n)}$$
for
$$f(n)=\frac{n}{20}+\frac{n^2}{9}+\frac{n^3}{59}\ ,$$
where the "graph" of an exponential sum means the sequence of partial sums, plotted in the complex plane, with successive points joined by straight line segments."

This intrigued me, so I decided to investigate. My findings and questions are below.

---

**Reproducing it in Desmos: (for those interested)**

I first decided to recreate the picture on Desmos. You can see it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pcbhiv9wb1) (it will take a while to load).

I created the image by defining $f(x)$ as it is defined above, then setting 
$$
x_2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{x}\cos(2\pi f(k))\\
y_2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{x}\sin(2\pi f(k))\\
p(x)=(x_2(x),y_2(x))
$$
So that $p(x)$ was essentially $\sum_{k=1}^{x}e^{2\pi i f(k)}$. Then I defined the lists 
$$\begin{align}
I_1&=[1,2,\dots,1000]\\
I_2&=[1001,1002,\dots,2000]\\
\dots &\dots\\
I_{10}&=[9001,9002,\dots,10000]
\end{align}$$
Then entering $p(I_{1}),\ p(I_2),\ \text{etc.}$ gave a whole bunch ($10000$ to be precise) of points. Then clicking the little gear symbol and then the colored circle next to each entry (on the left) I was able to connect the points $p(i)$ and $p(i+1)$ for any integer $1\leq i\leq 9999$. I used the $10$ different lists instead of $1$ in order to keep Desmos from freaking out.

---

**My investigations:**

Also using Desmos and the same technique as described above, I decided to create the graphs corresponding to the functions $$H_n(x)=x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\dots+\frac{x^n}n\qquad (n>1)$$
i.e. I made the graphs for $$p(k)=\left(\sum_{r=1}^{k}\cos[2\pi H_n(r)],\sum_{r=1}^{k}\sin[2\pi H_n(r)]\right)$$
I made each sequence/graph have $700$ points (AKA I graphed $p([1,2,...,700])$) just to see if any irregular behavior started to occur. Here are the graphs for the first $6$ values of $n$.

$n=2$:
[image: Coordinate system with red line from -1 to 0]

$n=3$:
[image: Coordinate system with regular hexagon whose upper horizontal line goes from -1 to 0]

$n=4$:
[image: Three-pointed star containing the same line]

$n=5$:
[image: Zig-zag circle (15-pointed star with inner circle close to outer circle)]
I do not know how well you can see it, but the points are starting to move around a little. This is a picture of the $n=5$ graph when I zoomed in on one of the corners:
[image: Magnification of one corner of the above, showing that each line and corner is really many close lines and corners]

$n=6$:
[image: Pretty complex shape]
Needless to say, the wiggly effect has been amplified. For comparison, here's the $n=6$ graph of $p([1,2,...,31])$:
[image: Shape with 5-fold symmetry, looking somewhat like a paddle wheel with attached triangles]

$n=7$:
[image: Another pretty complex shape]
Which is very far from well behaved. I think its 'supposed' to look something like the graph of $p([1,2,...,105])$:
[image: Another paddle wheel with attached triangles, now with 17 paddles]
Although even that has some drifty looking points.

You can look at more of these graphs by changing the value of $n$ on [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x5necptzc1).

---

**Questions:**

At this point I'm fairly certain that the strange behavior (as demonstrated by the cases $n=5,6,7$) can be attributed to the accumulating numerical inaccuracies of Desmos. For example, Wolfram evaluates 
$$A=\sum_{r=1}^{700}\exp[2i\pi H_{7}(r)]$$
as 
$$A= -11.470821630307989891763598910658573978486117477630759175...\\ -
3.6768673678262517039383839969453158461799151084757854088... i$$
and provides [a monstrous closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Br%3D1%7D%5E%7B700%7Dexp(2ipi(r%2Br%5E2%2F2%2Br%5E3%2F3%2Br%5E4%2F4%2Br%5E5%2F5%2Br%5E6%2F6%2Br%5E7%2F7))). Whereas Desmos puts the sum at the wildly incorrect 
$$1.3535617164+9.88880050357i$$
I did the same sort of test with $B=\sum_{r=1}^{20}\exp[2i\pi H_5(r)]$ and Wolfram gave 
$$B=-6.3944653536668510841041628532095052345320229467766883302... \\+
1.0127838162151622424794134150036094634983505690619992502... i$$
And Desmos gave 
$$-6.39446535424+1.01278381623i$$
Which is conclusive evidence that Desmos gets less accurate as $n$ and $x$ grow.

That was the subject of my original question, but it seems to have been resolved by now.

> So my question is how do we find a general formula for $\pi_n\in\Bbb N$ such that 
>   $$\forall k\in\Bbb N,\quad f_n(k+\pi_n)=f_n(k)$$
>   where $$f_n(k)=\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\exp[2i\pi H_n(\ell)]$$
>   I found the first few values:
>   $$\pi_2=2\\
> \pi_3=6\\
> \pi_4=6\\
> \pi_5=30\\
> \pi_6=30$$
>   But there's got to be some other way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $f(x) = x/20 + x^2/9+x^3/59, f(x+1)-f(x) = 27 x^2/531 + 145x/531+1891/10620$, $a(n) = e^{2i \pi f(n)}, A(n) = \sum_{l=1}^n a(l), a(531k+ n) = a(531 k) e^{2i \pi (f(n+531k)-f(531 k))}$ the point is that $e^{2i \pi (f(n+531k)-f(531 k))} = \prod_{l=1}^n e^{2i \pi (f(l+531k)-f(531 k+l-1))}$ doesn't depend on $k$ so $A(531k+n) = A(531k)+a(531 k) A(n)$ and the plot repeats itself at an angle $a(531k)$ and origin $A(531k)$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we focus on the equation
$$
f(k)=\sum_{l=1}^k e^{\imath 2 \pi H(l)}
$$
for some function $H(x)$ and search for an integer $\Delta$ such that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \qquad f(k+\Delta) = f(k),
$$
we find
\begin{eqnarray}
0 
& = & \left[ f(k+1+\Delta) - f(k+1) \right] - \left[f(k+\Delta) - f(k) \right]\\
& = & \left[ f(k+1+\Delta) - f(k+\Delta) \right] - \left[f(k+1) - f(k) \right]\\
& = & e^{\imath 2 \pi H(k+1+\Delta)} - e^{\imath 2 \pi H(k+1)}
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, we find that the problem reduces to finding an integer $\Delta$ such that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \qquad H(k+\Delta) - H(k) \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
If we restrict ourselves to $H(x)$ being a polynomial of degree $n$ with rational coefficients, it can be formulated as:
$$
H(x) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i,
$$
for some $N,a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and there is no common divisor in the set of $\{a_i\}$. It follows that
\begin{eqnarray}
H(k+\Delta) - H(k) 
& = & \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \left[(\Delta+k)^i - k^i \right]\\
& = & \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^i \binom{i}{j} \Delta^j k^{i-j}\\
& = & \frac{\Delta}{N} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{i}{j+1} \Delta^j k^{i-j-1} \in \mathbb{Z} \qquad (*)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence that the denominator $N$ of the rational polynomial $H(x)$ is a correct solution for $\Delta$.

Note, however, that $N$ is not necessarily the smallest solution for $\Delta$, but that the smallest solution for $\Delta$ will have to be a divisor of $N$. In fact, the series of polynomial $H_n(x)=\sum_i \frac{x^i}{i}$ would have the corresponding denominators $N_n=2,6,12,60,60,\dots$ for $n \geq 2$ and the OP already established that there are smaller solutions.

Finding the smallest solution of $\Delta$ is relatively straightforward, as one can simply check the validity of $(*)$ for all $k$ by dividing out respective (prime)factors $d$ from $N$, i.e., if $N = d \Delta$ than $(*)$ requires that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{i}{j+1} \Delta^j k^{i-j-1} \equiv 0 \mod d \qquad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}
$$
for which it is sufficient to check the values $0 \leq k < d$.

**Addendum**:
In view of the observation by the OP (25/10/2019) that the periods $\pi_n$ appear to be the primorial numbers. We consider the particular set of functions
$$
H_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}
$$
more closely. The goal is to find the smallest $\pi_n$ such that $H_n(x+\pi_n) - H_n(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $x$. In order to do so, we focus on the simpler set of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$ and find their corresponding period. This is equivalent to solving the smallest $\pi$ for which
$$
(x+\pi)^n \equiv x^n \mod n \qquad\text{for all $x$}\qquad (**)
$$
In particular this should be true for $x=0$, and hence $n\# | \pi$, where the  primorial $n\#$ is the product of all its prime factors
$$
n\# = \prod_{\text{prime } p \leq n} p
$$
In what follows we will see that $\pi=n\#$ is sufficient and therefore the smallest positive solution.

First we will show that for any prime $p$ and non-negative integer $l$, we find that for any integer $x$ 
$$
p^{l+1} | (x+p)^{p^l} - x^{p^l}
$$
This follows from induction by realising that for $l=0$ it says $p|(x+p)-x$ and the general factorisation expression
$$
\frac{(x+p)^{p^{(l+1)}} - x^{p^{(l+1)}}}{(x+p)^{p^l} - x^{p^l}} = (x+p)^{p^l(p-1)} + (x+p)^{p^l(p-2)}x^{p^l} + \cdots + x^{p^l(p-1)} \equiv p x^{p^l(p-1)} \equiv 0 \mod p
$$

It follows that for $n=p^l m$ with any prime factor $p$, and co-prime integer $m$ we get
$$
(x+p)^n = \left[(x+p)^{p^l}\right]^m \equiv \left[x^{p^l}\right]^m = x^n \mod p^l
$$
and therefore also any period that is a multiple of $p$ would equally be allowed, in particular
$$
(x+\pi)^n \equiv x^n \mod p^l.
$$
Since this is valid for every prime $p|n$ we have proven (**).

It therefor follows that the smallest period $\pi$ for the function $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$ is given by 
$$
\pi = n\# = \prod_{\text{prime } p|n} p
$$

As a direct consequence, we can also conclude that for $H_n(x)$ the corresponding primorial $\pi_n$ will satisfy $H_n(x+\pi_n)-H_n(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$, because it is true for each of its individual terms.

However, the constraint on the periods of all of the individual terms in $H_n(x)$ is more restrictive than the case where it only needs to hold for their combination within $H_n(x)$ itself. Hence, although the primorial $\pi_n=n\#$ is indeed a correct solution, we can not yet conclude that it is also the smallest solution for $H_n(x)$.

Comment: This looks good (+1). I need to go eat dinner right now so I'll look at this more once I come back. If everything checks out I'll give you the bounty and accept your answer. Thank you very much for such a detailed (and general!) answer. :)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for all the effort :)

Comment: I am almost certain that the $\pi_n$ in the question are the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) numbers, the product of all the primes less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: I think you are correct. I can demonstrate that $\pi_n$ is a correct period for the particular function $H_n$, but not that it is the smallest. If you like, I can add the extension to the above answer.

Comment: That would be very nice :)